# app crashes in iphone 6

Tags: ios, swift

[image][image]In my app I need contact list of the user. My app works fine with iphone 4s, 5, 5s but it crashes in iphone 6. I don't know what is the problem. Please help me. Here is the method I am using to get contactlist.

```
    let authorizationStatus = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()

    let addressBookRef: ABAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .Denied, .Restricted:

        println("Denied")

    case .Authorized:

        println("Authorized")

        let allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef).takeRetainedValue() as Array
        for record in allContacts {
            let currentContact: ABRecordRef = record
            let currentContactName = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(currentContact).takeRetainedValue() as String
            let unmanagedPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(currentContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty)
            let phones: ABMultiValueRef = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(unmanagedPhones.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as ABMultiValueRef

            let countOfPhones = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)

            for index in 0..<countOfPhones{
                let unmanagedPhone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index)
                let phone: String = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(unmanagedPhone.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as! String
                var params : Dictionary = ["name" : currentContactName, "number" : phone]

                self.phonesArray.addObject(params)

            }

        }

    case .NotDetermined:

        println("Not Determined")

        var err: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef) {
            (granted: Bool, error: CFError!) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if !granted {
                    println("Just denied")
                } else {
                    println("Just authorized")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what's the error message?

Comment: At what point does the app crash? On startup? Or do you perform some action to make it crash?

Comment: no it starts normal and every method except button which i use to get contact list works fine. when i press it app crashes

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the log?

Comment: of course u can see it on top

Comment: Could you print to log record type with ABRecordGetRecordType() function? Are you sure that record is not a source record (kABSourceType)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace "as String" with "as CFString"